# How to write two strings to a file in C and sort it?

Tags: c, string, file, sorting

i'm programming this Maze game in C. I have the strings `name[15]` and `score[15]`so when I print them the output is this "John 1000" so I need to write that output into a file every time the user finish the game and then if another user gets a higher or lower score sort it so the file should end up like this in 3 times running the game and finishing it:

1. Clark 25000
2. John 23000
3. Louis 21000

Answer (score 5):

What you should do is, each time a user finishes the game, you load the dynamicly allocated array, you sort it, then rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

First take a structure s with char str1[], char str2[] and struct s *next as fields. (For making linked list)
Since ' ' and '\n' are the delimiting characters here, read the first string till we hit ' ' into s->str1[] and in second string s->str2[] till we hit '\n' (After doing malloc() of the structure s)

So when new entry is to be added, we traverse through the list. If first node value (atoi(s->str2[]) is less than new entry's value; make the new entry as first node. If not, then traverse till linked list's node's value is less than the new entry's value.

So basically, we sort it while inserting into the list itself (descending wrt to values).

so if (a)6,(b)2,(c)7,(d)8,(e)5,(f)1 are the values we could sort like below:
1. (a)6->NULL
2. (a)6->(b)2->NULL
3. (c)7->(a)6->(b)2->NULL
4. (d)8->(c)7->(a)6->(b)2->NULL
5. (d)8->(c)7->(a)6->(e)5->(b)2->NULL
6. (d)8->(c)7->(a)6->(e)5->(b)2->(f)1->NULL